# Clear text object from in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a search feature in Corona SDK that displays results from my website. The first run works perfect but the second search results lay over top the old results.

txt_mybest get repeated and inserted in to a scroll view. I can figure out how to remove the previous results.

If I remove the scroll group it becomes unusable

```
local function sumbitConnented( event )
if ( event.isError ) then
local alert = native.showAlert( "Connection Error", "Your information was not sent. 
Please check your connection" , { "OK" }, onComplete )
else

nyHeight = 35

local t_ninja = json.decode( event.response )
for key in pairs(t_ninja) do

local xxteam_name = t_ninja[key]["team_name"]

nyHeight = nyHeight + 60
txt_mybest = display.newText("Team: "..xxteam_name,0,0,native.systemFont,13)
txt_mybest.anchorX = 0
txt_mybest.x = 85
txt_mybest.y = 38 +nyHeight
txt_mybest:setTextColor( 20/255, 20/255, 20/255 )
scroll:insert(txt_mybest)

end 



function onSearchRelease()
sendInfo = {["findTeam"] = findTeam.text}

local headers = {
["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
["Accept-Language"] = "en-US",
}
local params = {}
params.headers = headers
params.body = json.encode( sendInfo )
network.request( "http://www.website.com/team-search.php?f=hw&u_device="..muserID, "POST", sumbitConnented, params )
end
```

Hopefully "Bohemian" has the  mental ability to comprehend this question

Answer (score 0):

you can use txt_mybest.text= "your new text" .. this will change text for your display.newText object as long as the object exsits.

Comment: Thats would normally work but in this case I'm running it in a for loop inserting using the same name as many times as needed. basically I'm getting data from a server and displaying it out in a scroll. In order to have the results in rows I'm simply adding to the Y and inserting using the same name. Lol, I don't know if that makes sense or not

Answer (score 0):

You can add a display group in your scroll view and add all the text in it. When you want to remove the results, simply remove the group and add another one into scroll view. Like that you won't risk destroying your Scroll View and your results would clear off easily.